# ¿Cómo organizar un modelo MVC haciendo uso de DAO?

Tags: java, mvc, clase-abstracta

Quiero reorganizar mi aplicación usando el modelo MVC y el patrón DAO pudiendo ser adaptada a distintos tipos de bases de datos. Según he entendido quedaría organizado de la siguiente manera:

- En el modelo habría un interfaz para la conexión, simplemente con los métodos conectar y desconectar para que sea obligatorio el uso de estos al ser implementada por otra clase.
- También en el modelo una clase abstracta para la conexión y que implementa la interfaz anterior, con dichos métodos vacíos pero con los parámetros usuariodb, contraseñadb y nombredb.
- En el controlador habría una clase que heredaría de la clase abstracta de conexión del modelo y que dependiendo de la base de datos usada los métodos conexión y desconexión se implementarán de distinto modo. Podrían haber varias de estas, una por cada tipo de base de datos permitida.
- Siguiendo con el controlador, tendríamos una clase que incluiría las distintas operaciones CRUD a la base de datos, las cuales harían uso de llamadas a la clase abstracta de conexión tal que:
  **AbstractConection Conexion= new MySQLConection("Vicente", "73859", "bdPruebas");**
  Siendo new MySQLConection(....) como podría ser new NeodatisConection(....).
  As, en esta clase podría usar Conexion.conectar() y Conexion.desconectar() para realizar las conexiones y desconexiones independientemente del tipo de base de datos que use.
- En la vista directamente iría todo lo que el usuario ve. Yo en mi caso uso JavaFX para dicho propósito. Esta vista al necesitar de una acción CRUD llamaría a uno de los métodos del controlador CRUD, recogería y presentaría los datos.

Ahora me surgen preguntas.

1. ¿Es así como se debe hacer?
2. Si por ejemplo tuviese un objeto persona del cual crearía
   instancias, ¿en que parte del mvc debería alojarlo?
3. Si tuviese utilidades como pudiera ser encriptar una contraseña,
   ¿entraría dentro del mvc o debería tener una carpeta a parte que se
   llamase por ejemplo utils?

Comment: He encontrado en una web un tutorial que se adapta bastante bien a la respuesta que buscaba. [Visitar web.](http://www.ecodeup.com/crud-java-manual-completo/)